# Wordpress custom plugin that uses woocommerce enabled payment gateway for payment

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I have a certain special product that I do not want to be listed with other products, nor be added to the cart.

I want that specific product to have a fixed customized page where the user can pay for it immediately using any of the gateways of woocommerce that appears on the same page.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it seems to me that there are two different solutions you can try based on preference.

Option #1 would be to add a subdomain to your existing domain and basically set up a landing page for that one product. This way, you would be able to set up a separate Woocommerce on that subdomain and install a plugin like WooCommerce Quick Checkout to bypass the product page and cart page and go straight to checkout.

Option #2 would be to add that same plugin WooCommerce Quick Checkout on your existing site and create a page for that product. This may be the easier of the two options. The plugin can be found here: https://www.woothemes.com/products/quick-checkout/

Hope this helps.

Comment: I guess I can add that specific product to a certain filtered category so that it does not appear in product lists and use option #2. The quick checkout is great, thanks!